# substituir caracteres com .bat

Tags: cmd

Estou tentando substituir varias strings dentro de um arquivo, até consigo realizar alteração mais uma delas não quer alterar e nem localizar, segue me código e o que aparece na tela do CMD.

Estou tentando fazer isso pela um batch, o que eu quero é que acesso o arquivo `web.config.template`, na instrução

```
fart web.config.TEMPLATE  "Prefeitura Municipal de Uberlândia"  "Prefeitura Municipal de Araxa"
```

Quero que ele localize `"Prefeitura Municipal de Uberlândia"`  dentro do arquivo **web.config** e substiuta por  `"Prefeitura Municipal de Araxa"`

> #### Exemplo:
>
> Conteúdo do **arquivo.txt**
>
> ```
> Meu nome é Marcos Henrique
> ```
>
> ---
>
> após executar o **script.bat** o resultado deve ser:
>
> Conteúdo do **arquivo.txt**
>
> ```
> Meu nome é Fabio Vermieiro
> ```

segue link mais o menos do que quero fazer :

https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/substituir-caracteres-com-bat/590399

```
cls
echo off
cls
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Saude\Governa.Saude.Gestao
fart web.config.TEMPLATE "Server=srvhades,1100;Database=DB_SAUDE_GESTAO;User Id=SA;Password=;"                    "Server=srvjavabd,1433;Database=DB_SAUDE_GESTAO;User Id=admfsc;Password=municipio;"
fart web.config.TEMPLATE "Server=srvhades,1100;Database=DB_SAUDE_PROCEDIMENTO;User Id=SA;Password=;"              "Server=srvjavabd,1433;Database=DB_SAUDE_PROCEDIMENTO;User Id=admfsc;Password=municipio;"
fart web.config.TEMPLATE  "http://localhost/leitorbiometria/publish.htm"                                     "http://localhost:90/leitorbiometria/publish.htm" 
fart web.config.TEMPLATE  "Prefeitura Municipal de Uberlândia"  "Prefeitura Municipal de Araxa"
fart web.config.TEMPLATE  "http://localhost/Governa.Saude.Almoxarifado/Servicos/MaterialService.svc"       "http://localhost:90/Governa.Saude.Almoxarifado/Servicos/MaterialService.svc"
fart web.config.TEMPLATE  "http://localhost/Governa.Saude.Ambulatorio/Servicos/AmbulatorioService.svc"     "http://localhost:90/Governa.Saude.Ambulatorio/Servicos/AmbulatorioService.svc"
echo 
echo Realizado a alteracao no arquivo por completo....
```

resposta na TELA do CMD (*tem um que não altera `0 files`*)

```
Web.config.TEMPLATE
Replaced 1 occurence(s) in 1 file(s).
Web.config.TEMPLATE
Replaced 1 occurence(s) in 1 file(s).
Web.config.TEMPLATE
Replaced 1 occurence(s) in 1 file(s).
Replaced 0 occurence(s) in 0 file(s).
Web.config.TEMPLATE
Replaced 1 occurence(s) in 1 file(s).
Web.config.TEMPLATE
Replaced 1 occurence(s) in 1 file(s).
```

Comment: Seu problema ocorreu nas strings que usam acentos, tente repetir  seus comandos substituindo as ocorrências de acentos por **`?`**!

Comment: Exemplo: **`fart web.config.TEMPLATE  "Prefeitura Municipal de Uberl?ndia"  "Prefeitura Municipal de Araxa"`**

Comment: Coloquei ? mais mesmo assim ainda não altera a String, tem ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: vou baixar e ver alternativa q atenda, ele deveria dar suporte no uso de coringas: **`?`** e **`*`** ..   tente também: **fart web.config.TEMPLATE "Prefeitura Municipal de Uberl*ndia" "Prefeitura Municipal de Araxa"`**

Comment: Tentei com o * também, mesmo assim ele não reconhece

Comment: Tente assim, funcionou aqui: **`chcp 850 2>nul >nul & fart.exe -i .web.config.TEMPLATE Uberlândia Araxa`** n precisa usar *prefeitura de tal* por *prefeitura de tal* ...